# Using `InsertFile` and saving the file from website on IIS

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, com-interop

I am trying to add a file on a word document

```
application.Selection.InsertFile(file);
```

But it causes the exception

```
COMException: The document name or path is not valid
```

And then save it

```
document.SaveAs(path);
```

But then I get the exception

```
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))
```

The **exact same code** works when **running from Visual Studio**. The **exception** only happens when I try to **run from IIS**.

Could it be related to some permission? I have given full control permissions to `Everyone`, `ISUSR`, `Network`, `Network Service`, `System`, `Administrators`... And I also tried to use Impersonate with an administrator account.

**How can I fix it so it will work when I run from IIS?**

---

Here is the class I made to manipulate the doc: http://pastebin.com/yB2s0jn4

And here is how I am calling it

```
using (var doc = new HtmlWordDocument(outFile))
{
    // calls Selection.InsertFile( file )
    doc.WriteContent(tempFile);

    // calls document.SaveAs()
    doc.Save();
}
```

Comment: Did you verify File Security and the IIS AppPool's security account?

Comment: @Simon I added permission to `Everyone` with Full Control on the file's folder and configured IIS App Pool to use my administrator credentials. Nothing changed...

Comment: How about the tempFile Folder?

Comment: Hey I have the same problem, have you resolved? :((

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried impersonation ([How to implement impersonation in an ASP.NET application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158))? like below:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
    ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

    using (var doc = new HtmlWordDocument(outFile))
    {
        // calls Selection.InsertFile( file )
        doc.WriteContent(tempFile);

        // calls document.SaveAs()
        doc.Save();
    }

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need IISADMIN service enabled but it's not istalled by default, this service will permit to connect IIS to more OS resources

Check this...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28ddf643-0f9b-46e6-a8c5-a83f5a36c361/not-able-to-see-iis-admin-service-in-windows-server-2008-r2?forum=netfxbcl

and this...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555134